# How to choose value in key table with multiple choice

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table A with the following type for data

```
col1 | col2
--------
e1   | A
e2   | A
e3   | B
e4   | B
 .
 .
```

Basically in the col1, the id points to 2 same values. I would like to get a table without the col2 duplication. So something like:

```
 col1 | col2
    --------
    e1| A 
    e3| B
    e5| C 
     .
     .
```

Is there a way to achieve this in postgresql? I tried using the distinct keyword but they share the same id ...

Comment: Looks more like a `GROUP BY`!

Comment: Take a look at MIN or MAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `min` as follows:

```
Select min(col1) as col1,
       Col2
  From t
 Group by col2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (col2) t.*
from t
order by col2, col1 asc;
```

This selects all columns on the row.

If you want to delete rows, then you can use:

```
delete from t
    where t.col1 < (select max(t2.col1) from t t2 where t2.col2 = t.col1);
```